# Array type required - Pointer to Record

Tags: c++, delphi

I am trying to convert some C++ code into Delphi. Hopefully you can help.

This is the block of code that needs to be converted;

```
group = (inum - 1) / inodes_per_group;
index = ((inum - 1) % inodes_per_group) * inode_size;
inode_index = (index % blocksize);
desc[group].bg_block_bitmap;
blknum = desc[group].bg_inode_table + (index / blocksize); //Specifically this line
```

Now `desc` is declared as `EXT2_GROUP_DESC *desc;` which is defined elsewhere;

```
typedef struct tagEXT2_GROUP_DESC
{
    uint32_t    bg_block_bitmap;    /* points to the blocks bitmap for the group */
    uint32_t    bg_inode_bitmap;    /* points to the inodes bitmap for the group */
    uint32_t    bg_inode_table;     /* points to the inode table first block     */
    uint16_t    bg_free_blocks_count;   /* number of free blocks in the group        */
    uint16_t    bg_free_inodes_count;   /* number of free inodes in the          */
    uint16_t    bg_used_dirs_count; /* number of inodes allocated to directories */
    uint16_t    bg_pad;         /* padding */
    uint32_t    bg_reserved[3];     /* reserved */
}__attribute__ ((__packed__)) EXT2_GROUP_DESC;
```

`desc` is initalised using calloc as follows;

`desc = (EXT2_GROUP_DESC *) calloc(totalGroups, sizeof(EXT2_GROUP_DESC));`

First question; In C++, how is it possible to access a pointer to a record as an array like this? Why is there no array type required in C++?

Second question: Below is my Delphi conversion, why can I not access `desc` as an array without giving it a type?

My way is obviously wrong. What is the correct way to go about it?

```
Type
  PTExt2_Group_Desc = ^TExt2_Group_Desc;
  TExt2_Group_Desc = packed Record
    bg_block_bitmap : Cardinal;
    bg_inode_bitmap : Cardinal;
    bg_inode_table : Cardinal;

    bg_free_blocks_count : Word;
    bg_free_inodes_count : Word;
    bg_used_dirs_count : Word;
    bg_pad : Word;
    bg_reserved : Array[0..2] of Cardinal;
  end;

//Calloc function found from Google
function CAlloc(Items, Size: Cardinal): Pointer;
begin
  try
    GetMem(Result, Items * Size);
    FillChar(PByte(Result)^, Items * Size, 0);
  except
    on EOutOfMemory do
      Result := nil;
  end;
end;

self.desc := PTExt2_Group_Desc(calloc(totalGroups, sizeof(TEXT2_GROUP_DESC)));

  index := ((inum-1) MOD self.inodes_per_group) * self.inode_size;
  inode_index := (index MOD self.block_size);
  blknum := self.desc[group].bg_inode_table + (index div self.block_size); //Error - Array type required
```

Comment: But perhaps all you need is a dynamic array. Rather than translating literally without understanding the code it would be better to first understand and then write idiomatic delphi code

Comment: I'd write an answer if I knew what `self.desc` was. But guessing is no good.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question how is it possible (by which I take it you mean "sensible") to use a pointer as an array...

A pointer is simply a reference to an area of memory.  A typed pointer ensures that the layout of that memory conforms to a particular specification.  An array is merely a sequential arrangement of uniform memory areas, so an array reference applied to a base pointer is logically equivalent to simply taking an offset into the memory.  Instead of a byte offset, you are indicating an offset as a multiple (the array index) of a number of bytes, being the number of bytes occupied by the type referenced by pointer.

e.g. if you have a pointer **P** referencing memory that is a notional array of 16-bit words (2 bytes) then:

```
P[4] = P + (4 * 2) = P + 8 bytes
```

i.e P[4] = the 16-bit word located at **P** + 8

Now to the Delphi technique(s) involved:

If you are using Delphi 2009 or later, you can enable this syntax by enabling pointer arithmetic:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
```

If you are using an earlier version of Delphi, or prefer not to enable pointer arithmetic for some reason, you can achieve the same result by introducing an array type declaration:

```
TExt2_Group_Desc = packed record
  ..
end;

TExt2_Group_DescArray = array [0..255] of TExt2_Group_Desc;
PTExt2_Group_Desc = ^TExt2_Group_DescArray;
```

Doing this means that your pointer type must always be used as a reference to an array however, so you may prefer to create this array-form declaration as a separate type:

```
PTExt2_Group_Desc = ^TExt2_Group_Desc;
TExt2_Group_Desc = packed record
  ..
end;

TExt2_Group_DescArray = array [0..255] of TExt2_Group_Desc;
PTExt2_Group_DescAsArray = ^TExt2_Group_DescArray;
```

The bounds on the array are not strictly important (in terms of memory use) since you are not declaring a variable of that type, only using it as a way of coercing the array-form pointer type.   However, if you have bounds checking enabled then you should ensure that the bounds on this array declaration are sufficient to accommodate your required indexing range.

The **POINTERMATH** directive approach is not affected by this since there are no explicit bounds involved in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> First question; In C++, how is it possible to access a pointer to a
>   record as an array like this? Why is there no array type required in
>   C++?

To answer your first question, C++ has no notion of `Variable Length Arrays` (VLA).  Some C++ compilers offer this as an extension, but the ANSI C++ language specification outlaws them.

So the code you're seeing is one of many ways of compensating for the lack of VLA's.  Since arrays store data in contiguous blocks, all that needs to be done is declare a pointer, create the block dynamically (in the case above, using `calloc`), thus a pointer is returned that denotes the start of the array block.

Once the pointer points to this memory block, the array syntax of using `[ ]` can be used to access each element.

Note that the code you posted is mostly `C` in style.  There is very little reason (unless you're writing an allocator class) to use `calloc` in a C++ program.  In `C++`, you would usually use `new[]` to allocate memory for an array, or use a class such as `std::vector` to handle the memory management automatically.

Having said this, `C99` has VLA's, so the code above need not be done with this version of `C`.  For C++, there are no VLA's that are standard, so the code in your question would be used (albeit, very rarely).

---

As to your second question concerning Delphi, I guess the answer to the first question can be used as a guide.  I am not a Delphi programmer, but what you should investigate is whether Delphi has some sort of `dynamic array` class or type.  That would be the equivalent of the `calloc` call in C++.

Comment: There are no VLA's.  I'm assuming this is what is confusing the OP as to what that code is doing.

Comment: Why are you talking about VLAs? Isn't that going to confuse?

Comment: I don't think so.  If the code just said `EXT2_GROUP_DESC desc[totalGroups]`, the OP may have understood right away what this is, and maybe asking why it isn't as simple as this.

Comment: "If the code said". So where are the VLAs or did you introduce them?

Comment: I introduced them in my explanation.  I'm simply trying to convey why the pointers are used, as opposed to the simple array declaration that normally (or seemingly) would be used.

Comment: I still can't understand why you introduce VLAs. I only see confusion from that. Still, never mind.